# Tomcat/9.0.0.M18 not logging into manager program

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication

I try to login through http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html and when I try to log in, the login screen just disappears and reappears. Any Help?

Part of the **server.xml** file:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>

  <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
description="User database that can be updated and saved"
factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

</GlobalNamingResources>
...
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />

  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>
```

**tomcat-users.xml**:

```
<tomcat-users>
   <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
   <role rolename="manager-script"/>
   <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
   <role rolename="manager-status"/>
   <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
   <role rolename="admin-script"/>
   <user username="role1" password="role2" roles=manager-gui/>
</tomcat-users>
```

In $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/**manager.xml**:

```
<Context docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager"
         privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" antiJARLocking="false">

</Context>
```